# Does x86 have an atomic increment that keeps the value that was stored?

Tags: assembly, x86, atomic

I have found `lock inc addr` but that doesn't keep a copy of the stored value around and even a read immediately after it in the same thread could come after a competing write.

The best solution I have found is a `load`/`inc`/[`cas`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare_and_swap) loop.

Comment: In C++11 std::atomic, [`fetch_add`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/fetch_add) `+ 1` does what you want.  Or more simply, [`operator++`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith), but then you can't use a weaker `memory_order_relaxed` to make it faster on non-x86 if you don't need a barrier.  (`lock xadd` implements `fetch_add`, returning the old value).

Comment: [Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39393850/995714)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`lock xadd` is your friend.

Answer (score 3):

see [atomic_impl.h](http://code.google.com/p/effocore/source/browse/trunk/devel/effo/codebase/addons/inl/include/impl/atomic_impl.h) for more x86/x86_64 atomic primitives and usage.